# python flask app in docker is not refreshing images in frontend

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am running a python flask app on Docker. The app consists of a frontend in which a user provides a search term and the app returns an HTML file with insights and images. The problem is that after the first time I try the app, the HTML file keeps returning the images of the first try.

If I erase cookies, the problem is solved. But I cannot ask a user to erase cookies every time she needs to use the app.

I tried using `os.remove` before saving every image, but this doesn't work.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from flask_restful import Api
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import math

application = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(application)
@application.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
@application .route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    term1  = request.form['term1']
    my_results_list = []
    
    def google_query(query, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
        query_service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)  
        query_results = query_service.cse().list(q=query, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
        return query_results['items']

    my_results = google_query(term1,'api_key','cse_id', num = 10)
    for result in my_results:
         my_results_list.append(result['link'])
            
    data = pd.DataFrame(my_results_list)

    values     = [1] * len(data)
    N          = len(values)
    values    += values[:1]
    angles     = [n/float(N)*2*math.pi for n in range(N)]
    angles    += angles[:1]
    plt.polar(angles,values, marker='.', color = 'red')

    temp  = 'graph'       
    temp = 'static/' + temp + '.png'
    plt.savefig(temp)
    
    html = []
    html.append("""<!DOCTYPE html><html>""")
    html.append("""<img src="{{url_for('static',filename='graph.png')}}"/>""")
    html = ' '.join(html)
    temp = 'templates/result_vf.html'
    print(html, file = open(temp,'w',encoding='utf-8'))
    return render_template('result_vf.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host=('0.0.0.0'), port=8080 ,debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're running?

Comment: The easiest fix would probably be to randomize the filename, so it's not always graph.png. You could md5 the query and use that name, or do uuid. 

An alternative option would be to create a new route that serves up the PNG. So your html would reference '/graph?q=query' and you'd add a route that creates the query and returns the raw PNG contents. This has the advantage that it doesn't leave any files around on the filesystem.

Comment: A final option would be to inline the image using base64 encoding.